# Using multiple images instead of bullet points CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi i have encountered a problem when trying to make my bullet points various images using css. this is my code if anyone could help me out that would be really helpful thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                list-style-type: Square;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .fastdiet {
                list-style-image: url("fastdiet.jpg");
                padding-top: 3px;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }
            .Midnight {
                list-style-image: url("Midnight.jpg");
                padding-top: 3px;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="fastdiet">This book is Number 1</li>
            <li class="Midnight">This book is Number 2</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the problem is ?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/QnzB2/

Comment: Realized I made a slight change to the css during testing.  Posted an answer that may help others with same problem before asking in a clearer way.

Comment: The problem was that the images were not showing up for me because i had not put list-style-position: inside; i have know fixed the problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have this rule:

```
ul {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

And the default position for list markers is : `list-style-position : outside`, which means that the markers are not within the margins of the list (since the margin is 0).  You can fix this by either changing the margin for the ul to the width of your images or by setting the position to inside.  See my working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/QnzB2/

Comment: Thanks anthony you fixed the problem for me once i put        list-style-position: inside;    it worked , thanks alot